# Cabal package difference between readPackageDescription and parsePackageDescription

Tags: haskell, cabal

Haskell package Cabal-1.24.2 has module Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse.
Module has 2 functions: readPackageDescription and parsePackageDescription.

When I run in ghci:

```
let d = readPackageDescription normal "C:\\somefile.cabal"
```

I got parsed GenericPackageDescription

But when I run in ghci:

```
content <- readFile "C:\\somefile.cabal"
let d = parsePackageDescription content
```

I got Parse error:

```
ParseFailed (FromString "Plain fields are not allowed in between stanzas: F 2 \"version\" \"0.1.0.0\"" (Just 2))
```

File example is a file that generated using cabal init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parsePackageDescription expects the file contents themselves to be passed it, not the file path they are stored at. You'll want to readFile first... though beware of file encoding issues. http://www.snoyman.com/blog/2016/12/beware-of-readfile

Comment: You are right. It's UTF8-encdoning problem. Thank you for saved time for me.